# Memory corruption on multiple 'strcat' with same src

Tags: c++, c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is a very easy problem but im stunned that i cant find a easy solution.
I am tring to create two strings that are path to files.
/Metadata/bitmap
/Metadata/Metadata.bin

but the second time i try to do the `strcat()` with the same src variable explodes into memory corruption

```
//create the dir strign to append
    char* metadata_dir = strdup(MNT_POINT);
    strcat(metadata_dir, "Metadata/");


    char* bitmap_file = strdup("");
    strcat(bitmap_file,metadata_dir);
    strcat(bitmap_file,"bitmap");
    printf("%s\n",bitmap_file);


    char* meta_file = strdup("");
    strcat(meta_file, metadata_dir);
    strcat(meta_file, "Metadata.bin");
    printf("%s\n",meta_file);
```

rigth in the line 
    `strcat(meta_file, metadata_dir);`
the memory corruption happens.

I am shure that metadata_dir is not corrupted because i can print it anywhere in the code and it looks fine.

The weird thing is that this happens depenend on the machine that is running on. In Ubuntu 64 works just fine. But in the 32bits version no.

Answer (score 4):

`strdup` is only guaranteed to return a buffer big enough for the string you're duplicating (null terminator included); it may not (and often will not) have room for concatenating other things to it. You're overwriting random memory when you write past the end of the string with `strcat`.

EDIT: the solution, of course, is to `malloc` a buffer large enough in advance, instead of letting `strdup` do that.

Comment: strcat does not alocate memory?

Comment: @Dreamable Nope. Never has. Never will.

Comment: @John3136 The OS is free to allocate a gigabyte if it wants to. In fact, all allocations are rounded up to a multiple of something; the exact value of something varies.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 So you advocate relying on "magic rounding" thereby introducing intermittent buffer overruns due to undefined behavior (you don't know what the rounding - if any is). Avoid the confusion and assume that when you ask for 3 bytes you get 3 bytes.

Comment: @John3136 I'm not advocating for anything. I'm just saying how it works — `malloc(300)` will return either null or a buffer that is _at least_ 300 bytes long. Should anyone rely on that? Of course not, but it explains (in part) why the errors are intermittent instead of always happening.

Answer (score 0):

Code fails as `metadata_dir` is only certainly big enough for `MNT_POINT`, not `MNT_POINT` and `"Metadata/"`

```
char* metadata_dir = strdup(MNT_POINT);
strcat(metadata_dir, "Metadata/");
```

---

To allocate **and** concatenate:

```
char *allocate_cat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
  size_t size2 = strlen(s2) + 1;
  char *s12 = malloc(len1 + size2);  // allocate enough room for both
  if (s12) {
    memcpy(s12, s1, len1);
    memcpy(s12 + s1, s2, size2);
  }
  return s12;
}
```